# Fetch returns promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, fetch

I need  help with fetch function.
I have `movie_genres_url` which returns

```
const movie_genres_url = {
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Action"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
]
}
```

I have `genresArray` which is used to filter

```
const genresArray= [28, 18, 53];
```

In return I got a promise
`Promise {<pending>}`
But I want a array

```
['drama','action']
```

```
const fetchMovieGenres = async genresArray => {
  const response = await fetch(movie_genres_url);
  const json = await response.json();

  const genres = await json.genres
    .filter(genre => genresArray.includes(genre.id))
    .map(genre => genre.name);

  return genres;
};
```

Comment: You want to return the `name`s of matched items of `genresArray` from `move_genres_url` array? Is that it or any other issue you are also facing?

Comment: A function using `fetch` is asynchronous and cannot immediately return a value. Returning a promise is the solution, not a problem.

Comment: @Nithish yes and also I want to return ```genres``` as array not promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` functions will return a `Promise`. So even though it looks like you are returning the value, but eventually a `Promise` will be returned.

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Below is an example of `fetch` and `async-await`.

```js
const getData = async() => {
  let res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
  let data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

getData()
  .then(r => { console.log(r) })
  .catch(e => { console.log(e) });
```

Coming to your another requirement of getting the names of the matched elements of genresArray from the response(i.e., `movie_genres_url`). You were almost there, just that we need another `Array.map` i.e., `.map(({ name }) => name)` to get only the names from the filtered elements. Below is the example.

```js
const genresArray= [28, 18, 53];
const movie_genres_url = {"genres":[{"id":28,"name":"Action"},{"id":12,"name":"Adventure"}]}

const getMacthedElements = (data, filterBy) => data.filter(({ id }) => filterBy.includes(id)).map(({ name }) => name);

console.log(getMacthedElements(movie_genres_url.genres, genresArray));
```

Also, there's no need of using `await` while using `Array.filter`. So your final code should be something like below

```js
const fetchMovieGenres = async genresArray => {
  const response = await fetch(movie_genres_url);
  const json = await response.json();

//Added `map(({ name }) => name)`
  const genres = json.genres.filter(({id}) => genresArray.includes(id)).map(({ name }) => name);
  return genres;
};

//While calling/using `fetchMovieGenres`, it can be something like below or 
//you can use `await` provided that this should be again wrapped in another `async` function.
fetchMovieGenres(genresArray).then(genres => { console.log(generes) }).catch(e => { console.log(e) });
```

Comment: If you want to use the result of the function `fetchMovieGenres`, then yes either `.then(...)` or `await` are the solutions.